# Dynamixel Controller Manager showing "waiting for dependencies"

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/Creatingmetacontroller

When I run the command

> roslaunch my_dynamixel_tutorial start_meta_controller.launch

Controller Manager shows following:

> [WallTime: 1467285671.993447] [f_arm_controller] not all dependencies started, still waiting for ['joint4_controller', 'joint3_controller', 'joint5_controller']...

The tutorial page doesn't talk about any dependencies. How can I fix this?
I am using ROS indigo in Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238509/dynamixel-controller-manager-showing-%22waiting-for-dependencies%22/) by [Astronirav](https://answers.ros.org/users/27124/astronirav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-06-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Montes](https://answers.ros.org/users/31916/montes/) on 2017-09-15**:
Hello, good afternoon.
¿Did you solve the problem?

Thank you very much.
Yours faithfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your  **start_meta_controller.launch**  change the port from  '**dxl_USB0**' to '**pan_tilt_port**'.

I guess there is a mistake in the tutorial itself.

---

Originally posted by [ajayguhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29038/ajayguhan/) with karma: 46 on 2017-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Montes](https://answers.ros.org/users/31916/montes/) on 2017-09-20**:
Thank you very much.